# XML read and getting values

Tags: c#, xml

How can I get a this: `val="icon.weapon_small_sword_i00"/>` from XML file by giving a `itemId`. I managed to do something like this but besides of choosing right `itemId` from file I dont know how to get the value I mentioned above. 
Thats a code I have:

```
int ItemId = 15;
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(@"D:\L2Eq\xml\items");
XmlNodeType type;
while (reader.Read())
{
    type = reader.NodeType;
    if (type == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
        if (reader.Name == "item")
        {
            if (Int32.Parse(reader.GetAttribute(0)) == ItemId)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader.GetAttribute(0));
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

And thats how XML file looks like:

```
<list xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="items.xsd">
<item id="1" type="Weapon" name="Short Sword">
    <set name="icon" val="icon.weapon_small_sword_i00" />
    <set name="default_action" val="equip" />
    <set name="weapon_type" val="sword" />
    <set name="bodypart" val="rhand" />
    <set name="random_damage" val="10" />
    <set name="attack_range" val="40" />
    <for>
        <set order="0x08" stat="pAtk" val="8" />
        <set order="0x08" stat="mAtk" val="6" />
        <set order="0x08" stat="rCrit" val="8" />
        <set order="0x08" stat="pAtkSpd" val="379" />
    </for>
</item>
<item id="2" type="Weapon" name="Long Sword">
    <set name="icon" val="icon.weapon_long_sword_i00" />
    <set name="default_action" val="equip" />
    <set name="weapon_type" val="sword" />
    <set name="bodypart" val="rhand" />
    <set name="random_damage" val="10" />
    <set name="attack_range" val="40" />
    <for>
        <set order="0x08" stat="pAtk" val="24" />
        <set order="0x08" stat="mAtk" val="17" />
        <set order="0x08" stat="rCrit" val="8" />
        <set order="0x08" stat="pAtkSpd" val="379" />
    </for>
</item>
</list>
```

Comment: Just as a FYI, always go for a TryParse instead of a direct Parse. Defensive code will be better in the long haul for you !

Comment: You're better off using the new XML api to read and write XML files. Take a look at the XDocument class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument(v=vs.110).aspx) and XElement class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XmlTextReader is a very clumsy way to deal with XML; I'd never use it. The old `System.Xml.XmlDocument` API is a much better choice:

```
var findID = "1";
string iconValue = null;

var xdoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

xdoc.Load(@"D:\L2Eq\xml\items");

iconValue = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/list/item[@id=" + findID + "]/set[@name='icon']/@val")?.Value;
```

Or you could use the shiny new LINQ to XML classes:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\L2Eq\xml\items");

iconValue = doc.Descendants("item")
    .Where(d => d.Attribute("id")?.Value == findID)
    .Descendants("set")
    .Where(x => x.Attribute("name")?.Value == "icon")
    .FirstOrDefault()?.Attribute("val")?.Value;
```